# What is time complexity for following Question? Can any one explain?

Tags: time-complexity

Find the time complexity of the following algorithm

```
for( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i = i*2)

     for( j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++)

          print(“Hello”)
```

Answer (score 1):

The total run time actually is `O(n)`. If you count the total times the print statement is executed, you will get something like
`1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + [...]`, with the last element being `2^k`, where `k=int(log(n))`. This is a finite geometric series that [sums to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) `2^(k + 1) - 1`. Now, for the purpose of big-O-calculations, the trailing -1 is irrelevant, therefore we are left with `2^(k + 1)`, which can be bounded by `2^(log(n)+ 1) = 2 * 2^log(n) = 2n`, and that is `O(n)`

I ran a few timing tests to confirm this:

```
n=1000: 0.0003411999996387749 sec
n=10000: 0.002242799999748968 sec
n=100000: 0.01614079999990281 sec
n=1000000: 0.1618631999999706 sec
n=10000000: 2.070383299999775 sec
```